# What "off topic" close reasons should this site have?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Lets suggest the reasons that we should have (or remove).     Submit one per answer and lets vote.  Then the moderators can make a decision based on the top items.

Comment: Gosh! only one! I have a long list longer than my arm!

Comment: You can certainly answer multiple times.   Having one reason per answer makes voting more meaningful.

Comment: I'd like more input on this before we roll anything out. Maybe we should invite mods from other SE sites to give their input?

Answer (score 4):

Questions relating to the marketing, design and development of web sites outside of your control are off topic for Pro Webmasters

Comment: Can we clarify this somewhat?  Technically Google is outside of our control and 90%+ of the questions are about them :)

Comment: Any suggestions for how to word it?

Comment: Admittedly struggling with that part.  I tend to think more in terms of what is allowed and then exclude everything else.

Comment: Same here. Easier to conceive the concept then it is to put it into words.

Comment: "Questions relating to the marketing, design and development of web sites outside of your control are off topic for Pro Webmasters"

How's that?

Comment: Better then what I have.

Answer (score 3):

Questions asking to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Pro Webmasters as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 2):

Anything with "How do I" in the sentence LOL.....

But seriously I'd like any legal questions to be agreed that they do not belong on PRO Webmasters, such questions as an example would be:

- Legal implications of Serving "Blah" Content
- Questions relating to licensing types (DMCA  / Creative Commons / MIT etc.)
- Any questions relating to writing terms of use, terms and conditions and privacy statements.
- And general questions asking is this legal?

There are many reasons why I'd like to see all type of legal questions forbidden, but for me this is because I believe they should do their own homework since the answers they could be viewing are wrong - also law changes from country to country, answers given could apply for one country but not another. New laws are forever being introduced and the current laws are sometimes changed too.... Just my 2 cents.

Comment: "Pro Webmasters are not lawyers.  Please consult with local legal consul regarding your web site's legal issue."

Answer (score 2):

This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help anybody else. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting.

Comment: Could we phrase this one as "unlikely to help anybody else" instead of "too localized"?

Comment: I think that is a great idea

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: I edited in my suggestion previous suggestion.  Another suggested change: "For example, individual website reviews and site specific troubleshooting are off-topic at Pro Webmasters."  -- Broaden the troubleshooting a bit and make it clear those aren't the only situations that would apply.

Comment: I changed the last sentence to imply there are other reasons. If anyone has better verbiage please feel free to edit my changes.

Comment: Sometimes a specific problem can provide a generalized solution that is beneficial to everyone.  For example, a bug in a recent version of a common/popular tool breaks an asker's site but s/he has no way to know that it's affecting everyone.  In this hypothetical (or straw man, your pick), the solution is one that benefits more than the individual.  How should we deal with those?

Comment: Not sure. I want to say that the process of closing/reopening will handle those but if we can find a way define those as to minimize the confusion and/or leave open good questions I'd like to see us take that route.